# mySql query show strange info

Tags: mysql

So i have this my sql query but it doesnt work exactly the way, it shows on the begining nulls values that shoudnt appear and repeat some lines, i want what am i doing wrong:

```
SELECT cd.id, cd.dt_ini_camp, cd.dt_fim_camp, cd.descricao, l.id_estab, 
   l.quantidade, 
   (SELECT SUM(quantidade) FROM lin_doc l WHERE l.id_cab_doc = cd.id) AS qtd 
FROM cab_doc cd 
RIGHT JOIN lin_doc l 
ON l.id_cab_doc = cd.id 
AND cd.id_tipo_doc = 1
```

***Output:***

descricao
id_estab
quantidade
qtd

NULL
12
362.000
NULL

NULL
19
452.000
NULL

NULL
14
154.000
NULL

NULL
05
492.000
NULL

Outras Campanhas
03
229.000
3971.000

Outras Campanhas
05
215.000
4388.000

NULL
06
162.000
NULL

NULL
17
22.000
NULL

NULL
34
39.000
NULL

NULL
13
63.000
NULL

NULL
28
162.000
NULL

NULL
29
43.000
NULL

NULL
03
190.000
NULL

Outras Campanhas
33
71.000
3971.000

NULL
02
13.000
NULL

NULL
08
170.000
NULL

NULL
06
409.000
NULL

***Desired output:***

descricao
id_estab
quantidade
qtd

Outras Campanhas
05
215.000
4388.000

NULL
06
162.000
NULL

NULL
17
22.000
NULL

NULL
34
39.000
NULL

NULL
13
63.000
NULL

NULL
28
162.000
NULL

NULL
29
43.000
NULL

NULL
03
190.000
NULL

Outras Campanhas
33
71.000
3971.000

NULL
02
13.000
NULL

NULL
08
170.000
NULL

NULL
06
409.000
NULL

Comment: Are you looking for a `LEFT JOIN` instead of the `RIGHT JOIN`?  Not sure I completely understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

First thing i would say there is no need to do a correlated subquery when you can get the sum within same query

```
SELECT cd.id, cd.dt_ini_camp, cd.dt_fim_camp, cd.descricao, l.id_estab, 
   l.quantidade, 
   COALESCE(SUM(l.quantidade) )AS qtd 
FROM cab_doc cd 
RIGHT JOIN lin_doc l 
ON l.id_cab_doc = cd.id 
AND cd.id_tipo_doc = 1
GROUP BY cd.id
```

Second for null result you can use `COALESCE()` ,since you haven't shown the table definitions so i used `GROUP BY cd.id`